# python3 can't run tokenize

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd

I run this program.Called [*Keitaisokaiseki*].

[image]

but I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Mao\Desktop\形態素解析　ランキング（栃木県）.py", line 23, in <module>
     tokens = t.tokenize(val)
   File "C:\Users\Mao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
    packages\janome\tokenizer.py", line 194, in tokenize
    return list(self.__tokenize_stream(text, wakati, baseform_unk))
    File "C:\Users\Mao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
    packages\janome\tokenizer.py", line 197, in __tokenize_stream
    text = text.strip()
   AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Line 194 is

```
    return list(self.__tokenize_stream(text, wakati, baseform_unk))
```

Line 197 is

```
    text = text.strip()
```

Give me any guidance.

Comment: `text` is clearly a `float`. Please show a [mcve]

Comment: can you please place your code in pastebin.com or some other codeshare place

Comment: @Vasif The code should go in the question itself

Comment: What is `val`? Do the examples work? http://mocobeta.github.io/janome/en/

Comment: I mean.. OP linked a image so was thinking at least pastebin might be improvement. and also seems like an package issue due to possibly a wrong input. May be package mantainers will like it..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you provided you are trying to do

```
tokenize(val)
```

where `val` came from reading an excel sheet with xlrd. As can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542274/python-xlrd-receiving-float-from-excel-text-cell) the return type from the xlrd call can be a float which explains your error as you are giving a float value to the tokenize function

Answer (score 0):

Seems you give float value to tokenize() method.

janome is a Japanese "text" analysis engine, so you need to cast numeric values to string before calling tokenize().